# Jenkins stop a build of specific job according to Parameter

Tags: jenkins, hudson

How can I stop a build of specific job according to it's Parameter

for example:

I run the job `FooJob` multiple times with different `FooParam` with the following url:

```
http://10.10.10.10:8080/job/FooJob/buildWithParameters?FooParam=15
http://10.10.10.10:8080/job/FooJob/buildWithParameters?FooParam=19
http://10.10.10.10:8080/job/FooJob/buildWithParameters?FooParam=24
```

I am looking for url that can stop `FooJob` that has `FooParam=19` if it's running

So I though if getting all the running builds of the job and check if it has the parameter `FooParam=19` than to stop it

How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the platform (linux,window, other platforms). select build step within your Jenkins job .Execute shell or execute windows batch script. Just check parameter using simple "if condition" .If fooparam ==19 then stop your build by using "exit 0" (success) or "exit 1" (fail).